# redux useSelector hook returns array from state that is set by redux-sagas but i cant .filter() over it

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am just writing up a a small site that fetches list of repositories for a given user and displays them in a grid.

To achieve it i am using probably an overkill combination of redux, redux-sagas, axios and redux-hook.

First thing i do is i have a `httpClient` that does the async call to fetch the repos which returns array of objects `[{},{},{}]`

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getProjects = async () => {
  return await axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/xxx/repos", {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  });
};
```

inside my Container component which is loaded when the app mounts i dispatch a action to trigger the redux cycle:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProjectsRequest());
  }, []);
```

the Action:

```
export const getProjectsRequest = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_REQUEST,
})
```

This is then captured by my saga where i yield my `httpCLient` that return the array of objects and passes the payload onto `getProjectsSuccess(result.data)` which is :

```
export const getProjectsSuccess = (projects) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      projects
    }
})
```

SAGA:

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, fork } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { ActionTypes } from "../actionTypes";
import * as actionProjects from "../actions/projectsAction";
import * as http from "../../api/httpClient";

// Worker Saga
function* fetchProjects() {
  try {
    const result = yield call(http.getProjects);
    yield put(actionProjects.getProjectsSuccess(result.data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    yield put({ type: "GET_PROJECTS_FAILED", message: error.message });
  }
}

function* watchGetProjectsRequest() {
  yield takeEvery(ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_REQUEST, fetchProjects);
}

const projectsSagaResult = [fork(watchGetProjectsRequest)];

export default projectsSagaResult;
```

This is the captured in my reducer and updates the state accordingly with array of objects:

case ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS: {
return {
isLoading: false,
...action.payload,
};
}

**FINALLY:**

In my projects.js component where i am trying do loop and display all the projects from GITHUB user i use   `const { projects } = useSelector((state) => state.gitHubPortfolio)`
so that i can access the state slice and filter over it like so:

```
const test = projects.filter(x => {return x.name === "m" })
```

This instantly throws a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
```

But when i step through the code in the browser i can do this without the error so the useSelector fetches array of objects from the state.

[image]

Now i the console i can simply filter projects array whilst inn debugger mode like so:

[image]

**AT LAST**
I have no idea why i cant filter through the projects array inn my code, but it seems to me like its some `PROMISE` issue it might be that the projects are not set before i am trying to filter them i really have no idea.

Comment: What is the initial value, can you share the reducer too?

Comment: @MartinKadlec
i can do .filter on the projects in my code only if i use if statmennt: ```  
if (projects) {
    console.log('HELLO', projects.filter(x => {return x.name === "m" }))
  }```

so when the app load projects are not ready but become available later